# Remove watermark "DEMO" appearing in PDF background

Tags: pdf, itext

While Open Reports as pdf format i'm getting watermark as "DEMO" in background. I'm using iText 2.1.4

How to remove this watermark? It's shown in this image

[image]

Comment: Unless your iText version has been manipulated by someone to add that DEMO background automatically, this addition is explicitly done by request of the caller, be it Open Reports itself or some PDF export module of it.

Comment: The allegation is false: iText has never added a watermark to PDF (unless you program it that way).

Comment: Thanks everyone i got yours words,i have to find that watermark in code... @BrunoLowagie - Everytime I use import com.lowagie im using your name,So will respect your words im going to use latest version of itext in my Applications...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm sorry for suggesting that iText adds watermarks to PDFs as part of a licensing setup. I should've investigated before making that claim and I shouldn't have presented that as an answer.

Comment: No problem. Things like this happen ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official versions of iText (either free or paid) **NEVER** added a watermark to files generated with the lib. This could be added either by your own code, or by a wrapper if you don't use iText directly.

Also note you are using a very old version of iText, almost [5 years old](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/214). This version (and in fact, any version prior to 5.x) presents [legal and technical issues](http://lowagie.com/iText2). If possible, an upgrade would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VeryPDF's PDF Text Replacer Command Line to remove this "DEMO" text to space.

Comment: Are you sure that "DEMO" is drawn as text? The text replacer can be used to replace text drawn using text showing commands, but the "DEMO" the OP observed may also have been drawn using vector graphics or using a bitmap...